# How to make regex matching group excluding the matching characters?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to match/extract the word `test` in the string `asd{test}asd`.

My Regex: `({test}.*)` would match `{test}`. How do I:
- match anything inside the brakets?
- exclude the brakets from the matching group?
- make the matching group optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms like `(?<=\\{)[^}]*(?=\\})`

Demo:

```
String data = "asd{test}asd";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)[^{}]*(?=\\})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output: `test`

Explanation:

- `[^{}]*` - will match zero or more non `{` or `}` characters
- `(?<=\\{)` - which have `{` before it (we needed to escape `{` here since it is regex metacharacter)
- `(?=})` - and `}` after it
  (we didn't have to escape `}` here because it is not part of `{..}` quantifier)

Answer (score 0):

use `({(test)}.*)` and get `group(1)` .

Comment: Would it not better to make the outer non-matching group, like `(?:{(test)}.*)`?